# Assigning Term Store Administrator on SharePoint Online using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, taxonomy

I am trying to setup a SharePoint Online Site Collection 100% programmatically via the CSOM in a .Net application.

I have been able to create the Site Collection itself, sub-sites and lists, but I am unable to create a new Taxonomy Group and Sets since my user is not assigned as the Term Store Administrator. If I assign myself as the Term Store Administrator through the Term Store Management Tool UI my code works exactly as I need it to.

Is there a way to assign a user as the Term Store Administrator only using the c# object model? Assume the context is running under a user that has sufficient rights to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to assign a user as TermStore Administrator using CSOM. 
But one thing you could do is to create a new user (similar to service account) and make that user TermStore Administrator. Run the code to create term group under the context of that user.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/"))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();

    foreach (char c in "yourpassword".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("loginname@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);//Pass credentials of the new user you have created
}
```

Comment: I support that. There is no way. I even check the api myself in SharePoint and I couldn't find any sign of such a function. Better say that it's not possible even thow it's not the expected answere.

Comment: This doesn't really work because I'm not controlling the SharePoint instance I want to use. But since you did answer the question (even with the negative) I'll give you the bounty.